# How to set margins fot html2canvas for the entire page?

Tags: angular, html2canvas, html-to-pdf, pdfmake

I'm trying to convert a html to pdf and to save it. I am using jsPDF and htmlToCanvas for it. I set a div over the entire page and take this in as an element. Only the table gets printed. I don't get the header, nor the div box below the table. I can mess things up and try to put them in the table, but I would prefer not work messy like that. How can make sure the entire page gets printed? Or how can I add multiple values to the DATA?

html page:

```
<div *ngIf="order" id="pdfOrder" #pdfOrder>
<app-client-info></app-client-info>

    <table id="productTable">
        <thead>
      values
        </thead>
      
        <tbody>
       values
        </tbody>   
      
      </table>

      <div class ="costbox">
       values
              <div>
                <button (click)="goback()">Back</button>
                <button (click)="confirmOrder()">Confirm</button>
              </div>
      </div>



</div>
```

relevant code in ts file:

```
  @ViewChild('pdfOrder') pdfOrder!: ElementRef;


  confirmOrder(): void {

    let DATA: any = document.getElementById('pdfOrder');
    html2canvas(DATA).then((canvas) => {
      let fileWidth = 208;
      let fileHeight =100; //(canvas.height * fileWidth) / canvas.width;
      const FILEURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      let PDF = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');
      let position = 0;
      PDF.addImage(FILEURL, 'PNG', 0, position, fileWidth, fileHeight);
      PDF.save('test.pdf');
    })

    this.salesproductService.submitOrderedItems(this.order);
    this.router.navigate(["/main"]);
  }
```

Html that should be printed:

[image]

screenshot of the output:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is still unclear why it doesn't convert all elements within the div, but using DaTA = document.body gives the entire page.

Answer (score 0):

It's still not clear if the elements are not getting printed due to some margin in the top

```
margin-top:-50px
```

try this style in the top div and see if you have any changes in the outout , if the changes are visible then , it's because of the margin issue .

Comment: Margins didn't help. For some reason, it doesn't take all the elements within the div, only the table values. Using document.body took everyting.. Than just make sure buttons aren't visible and done :D